# Limit number of uploaded files

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to limit the number of files uploaded using php. Heres my code:

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
if(isset($file ['name'][1])) {
    echo json_encode(array('multipleFiles' => 'Multiple Files Uploaded'));
    exit();
}
```

The if statement runs when I upload 1 file only. How can I check and limit the number of uploaded files using php?

Comment: Can the down voter please explain???

Comment: does your form allow multiple files to be uploaded?

Comment: `if(count($_FILES['name'] >1)){exit ('bad');}`

Comment: @Dagon That works. Thanks!

Comment: let me upgrade that to an answer:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

counting one of the $_FILES array should work:

```
  if(count($_FILES['name'] >1)){
    exit ('bad');
    }
```